# How to iterate over array of integers to find a sequence based on an O(N) solution?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I saw following question and tried to find an answer for that.

```
Question:  Given a sequence of positive integers A and an integer T, return whether there is a *continuous sequence* of A that sums up to exactly T
Example
[23, 5, 4, 7, 2, 11], 20. Return True because 7 + 2 + 11 = 20 
[1, 3, 5, 23, 2], 8. Return True  because 3 + 5 = 8
[1, 3, 5, 23, 2], 7 Return False because no sequence in this array adds up to 7

Note: We are looking for an O(N) solution. There is an obvious O(N^2) solution which is a good starting point but is not the final solution we are looking for.
```

My answer to above question is:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = {23, 5, 4, 7, 2, 11};
        System.out.println(isValid(myArray, 20));
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[] array, int sum) {
        int pointer = 0;
        int temp = 0;

        while (pointer < array.length)
        {
            for (int i = pointer; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] > sum)
                    break;

                temp += array[i];
                if (temp == sum)
                    return true;
                else if (temp > sum)
                    break;
                // otherwise continue
            }

            temp = 0;
            pointer++;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I think my answer is O(N^2) which is not acceptable based on Question. Is there a solution based on O(N)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to loop once actually which is O(N).

Start adding from index 0 and once you exceed the `sum` start removing from the beginning of the array. if `temp` falls below `sum` continue looping.

```
  public static boolean isValid(int[] array, int sum) {
    int init = 0,temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      temp += array[i];
      while (temp > sum) {
        temp -= array[init];
        init++;
      }
      if (temp == sum)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to have two indices (start and stop) then you increase `stop` until the sum is the required (and return `true`) or above. Then you increase `start` until the sum is the required (and return `true` or below. Then you repeat this until you reach the end of the array. You can update the sum incrementally (add the element when you increase `stop` and subtract when you increase `start`). This ought to be O(N).

Here's an example:

```
public class t {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = {23, 5, 4, 7, 2, 11};
        System.out.println(isValid(myArray, 20));
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[] array, int sum) {
        int start = 0;
        int stop = 0;
        int tsum = 0;

        while( true )
        {
            if( tsum < sum )
            {
                if( stop >= array.length )
                    break;
                tsum += array[stop];
                stop++;
            }
            else if( tsum > sum )
            {
                tsum -= array[start];
                start++;
            }
            else if( tsum == sum )
                return true;

            // System.out.println(start + " -- " + stop + " => " + tsum);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```